# Loop through array and populate matrix - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

I want to populate matrix table dynamically. I have this part of API response:

```
"Characteristics": [
            {
                "Description": "Benefits - Pay Related",
                "Years": [
                    2018,
                    2017,
                    2016
                ]
            },
            {
                "Description": "Benefits - Preapproved",
                "Years": [
                    2018,
                    2017,
                    2016
                ]
            },
            {
                "Description": "Benefits - Age/Service Weighted Plan",
                "Years": [
                    2018,
                    2017
                ]
            },
            {
                "Description": "Benefits - Profit Sharing",
                "Years": [
                    2018,
                    2017,
                    2016
                ]
            },
            {
                "Description": "Benefits - 404c",
                "Years": [
                    2018,
                    2017,
                    2016
                ]
            },
            {
                "Description": "Benefits - Participant Directed",
                "Years": [
                    2018,
                    2017,
                    2016
                ]
            },
            {
                "Description": "Benefits - 401(K)",
                "Years": [
                    2018,
                    2017
                ]
            },
            {
                "Description": "Benefits - 401(m) Arrangement",
                "Years": [
                    2018,
                    2017,
                    2016
                ]
            },
            {
                "Description": "Benefits - Auto Enrollment",
                "Years": [
                    2018,
                    2017
                ]
            }
```

As you can see the "Description" always exist, but not for all years. In the end I want to have something like this rendered:

[image]

The provided table is not related to the data - as you can see for "Benefits - Age/Service Weighted Plan" there is no 2016 in "Years" so I want there to be 'N'. I have function to detect unique years from other part of the data which containing all years for which any information is provided. This is in API response:

```
const uniqueYearsPension = data => {
  return data.map(element => {
    return element.Year;
  });
};
```

I tried populating table like this:

```
<table className="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm table-hover">
                  <thead className="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                      <th>Description</th>
                      {DataExtract.uniqueYearsPension(
                        props.types[2][index]
                      ).map((el, ind) => {
                        return <th key={ind}>{el}</th>;
                      })}
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody className="table-hover">
                    {element.Characteristics &&
                      element.Characteristics.map((e, i) => {
                        return (
                          <tr key={i}>
                            <td>{e.Description}</td>
                            {e.Years.reverse().map((year, yearID) => {
                              console.log(year);
                              return DataExtract.uniqueYearsPension(
                                props.types[2][index]
                              ).map((el, ind) => {
                                console.log(year);
                                if (year == el) {
                                  return <td key={yearID}>Y</td>;
                                }
                              });
                            })}
                          </tr>
                        );
                      })}
                  </tbody>
                </table>
```

But it is populating row 1 by 1 and if 2016 is missing it is putting 2017 result in this column and so 2018 is empty instead of 2016 - which is absolutely normal. If I add else statement here:

```
if (year == el) {
                                  return <td key={yearID}>Y</td>;
                                } else return <td key={yearID}>N</td>
```

It is printing on the row many many results. Any ideas how to populate my table like a matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to save the result of `uniqueYearsPension` into a variable at first to avoid recalculation.
And then during the render `tr` just map on all years and check whether `e.Years` includes the value.
The code would look like:

```
const uniqueYears = DataExtract.uniqueYearsPension(props.types[2][index]);
...
...
<table className="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm table-hover">
    <thead className="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>Description</th>
            {
                uniqueYears.map((value, key) => {
                    return <th key={key}>{value}</th>;
                })
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody className="table-hover">
        {element.Characteristics &&
            element.Characteristics.map((e, i) => {
                return (
                    <tr key={i}>
                        <td>{e.Description}</td>
                        {
                            uniqueYears.map((year, yearID) => {
                                if (e.Years.includes(year)) {
                                    return <td key={yearID}>Y</td>;
                                } else {
                                    return <td key={yearID}>N</td>;
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    </tr>
                );
            })}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes. This worked. Skipping interaction resolved the issue